# How to mask out a region of a view

Tags: view, swiftui, shapes, masking

I am looking for advice on the best way to achieve the following with SwiftUI.

I have a view with a red rounded rectangle corner, and a child view which is a rectangular blue box offset to the bottom of the parent. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtJY0.png)

However, I wish to mask out the the hatched area in the second attached figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB1yE.png) so that is appear white (i.e. remove the blue hatched area) and am not sure how to best accomplish this.

This is the code as it stands:-

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct PupilCell : View {
    var body : some View {

        ZStack { 

            Rectangle().frame(height: 60.0, alignment: .bottom).foregroundColor(Color.blue).offset(x: 0.0, y: 50.0)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous).stroke(lineWidth: 2.0).fill(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you have to use Shape for this....see this Apple tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach:

[image: mask for rects]

```
ZStack {

    Rectangle().frame(height: 60.0, alignment: .bottom).foregroundColor(Color.blue).offset(x: 0.0, y: 50.0)
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous).stroke(lineWidth: 2.0).fill(Color.red)
}.mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous).fill(Color.black))
```

Comment: but it works also with .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)) :D

Comment: Yes @Chris, in this particular case simplified variant also works. I wanted to show generic principle of masking by top view, which not always would have simplified default parameters. Just in case.

Comment: i didn't want to reduce your solution - i didn't know how to do it without custom shape....you solution is great ;)